Importing a GeoJSON file
I have this GeoJSON file which I'd like to import into Blender 4.1.0 (Ubuntu 22.04.4):
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -110.780169,
              43.729045
            ],
            [
              -110.780135,
              43.729055
            ],
            [
              -110.779909,
              43.729171
            ],
            [
              -110.779801,
              43.729303
            ],
            [
              -110.779674,
              43.729266
            ],
            [
              -110.779506,
              43.729272
            ],
            [
              -110.779361,
              43.729416
            ],
            [
              -110.77914,
              43.729487
            ],
            [
              -110.778934,
              43.729456
            ],
            [
              -110.778733,
              43.729455
            ],
            [
              -110.778479,
              43.72953
            ],
            [
              -110.77832,
              43.729545
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "1",
      "properties": {
        "type": "Path",
        "fcolor": "RED",
        "routeMode": "WALKING",
        "showLength": false
      }
    }
  ]
}

For the sake of simplicity, it has just one feature, but it can have several. It may also be of other types (MultiPoint or MultiPolygon).
How could I properly achieve that, keeping its attributes?

what did u try? where did u fail? this site is not for tutorials or searching for voluntary work doing for others, but for one specific problem you have. If you search for somebody doing your job, you should go to sites like blenderartists.org, which have a section "voluntary work". This site is for one specific problem only, not for tutorials.

there's no way to import a GeoJSON that I'm aware of, maybe there's an add-on. Your options are to convert to a format Blender likes (maybe PLY can support edges/polylines). Last I checked, BlenderGIS could import shapefiles if you convert your GeoJSON, or BVTKNodes add-on supports VTK files, which can easily support this kind of data. beyond that, you're stuck writing a python function that defines the points/edges and point/edge attributes coming from the GeoJson.

Okay thank you Derek. I've dig into BlenderGIS lately, and indeed, converting to a Shapefile is probably the easiest way to go. But if BlenderGIS relies on GDAL, I would love to see other formats. Maybe I'll start a discussion with the developer.

@swiss_knight, if I remember correctly, you can optionally not have GDAL installed and some of the functionality just wont work.. I think the shpfile importer still does, but sounds like you're going down the right path. I actually created an add-on at work for this kind of thing :D but it's still internal...
